# Admob Error on some devices - insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

am facing strange issue with Admob. It is literally driving me crazy:

This is the setup I have;

1. Two apps (App1 and App2), both have same version of google play services (added as library to projects in eclipse).
2. I have 2 emulators configured as EM1 on API level 15 without google play service and EM2 with API level 23 with google play service)

When I run App1 on EM1 and EM2 -I get ads on both the emulators
When I run App2 on EM1 and EM2 - I get ads only on EM2 and not on EM1.

For App2 on EM1: I get the following error in logcat:

> W/Web Console(5169): The page at about:blank displayed insecure
>   content from
>   gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&pan_include=0&request_id=9065dcf0-1ce8-4c09-9c45-7a5a394b9f84&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D3707874891003926994%26seq_num%3D2%26rm%3D2%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v8487000.8487000.0%26hl%3Den%26submodel%3DAndroid%2520SDK%2520built%2520for%2520x86%26gnt%3D3%26ma%3D0%26carrier%3D310260%26platform%3Dunknown%26forceHttps%3Dtrue%26u_sd%3D2%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D0%26muv%3D11%26riv%3D5%26ms

It is very strange that App1 gets the admob ads on this emulator but not App2. I have extensively searched forum for the error but there is no information.

Please provide your inputs.